# Pointing a section/end of unsigned char array to a memory address

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, memory, append

Say I have an example byte array:

```
unsigned char byte_array[] = "\xff\x00\xaf\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
```

And say I also have a pointer that points to assembly opcodes:

```
unsigned char *opcodes = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
```

How do I point the last 8 bytes of `byte_array` to the memory address (not the data `opcodes` is pointing to) bytes of the pointer `opcodes` to `byte_array`? For instance say the memory address `opcodes` is pointing to is:

```
0x0000ffffffffffff8
```

I would want `byte_array` to be:

```
\xff\x00\xaf\xc1\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00
```

Essentially I need to somehow extract the memory address stored in the variable `opcodes` and assign that memory address to the last 8 bytes of `byte_array`.

Comment: First, you'll need to make that byte array bigger. Currently its only 5 bytes long.

Comment: I noted that at the last second I modified it.

Comment: Copy the bytes of `opcodes` to the desired bytes in `byte_array`.

Comment: I need to copy the memory address of `opcodes` to `byte_array` not the bytes `opcodes` is pointing to.

Comment: Variables in C do not move; they refer to a fixed area.  You can set a pointer to `opcodes + n` but you can't move `byte_array`

Comment: I'm not trying to move it just extract the memory address of `opcodes` so I can assign it to `byte_array`'s last 8 bytes.

Comment: So it's not possible then?

Comment: Who said to copy the bytes `opcodes` points to? I wrote to copy the bytes **of** `opcodes`, not the bytes it points **to**.

Comment: What if I allocated 8 more bytes on the stack for `byte_array` and then assigned the last 8 bytes to the memory address of `opcodes`.

Comment: Note that your `opcodes` don't use a 64-bit absolute address.  Compiling that C and running `objdump -D -rwC -Mintel`, I get `ff 00   inc  DWORD PTR [rax]` / `af   scasd` / `c1 00 00    rol DWORD PTR [rax],0x0`.  (And the rest of the zeros decode as `00 00  add    BYTE PTR [rax],al`.)  Dropping a 64-bit absolute address after the `c1` byte will decode the low byte of the address as a ModRM byte, which might take some later bytes as more addressing-mode bytes.  And one following byte will be the immediate rotate count.

Comment: x86-64 only has 64-bit absolute addressing for a special form of `mov`.  (to/from AL/AX/EAX/RAX).

Answer (score 2):

Like all objects in C, the value of a pointer is represented by bytes in memory. To make some other bytes point to the same bytes that a pointer is pointing to, one can simply copy the bytes representing the pointer to the other bytes:

```
memcpy(byte_array + offset, &opcodes, sizeof opcodes);
```

Here `offset` would presumably be five, to start after the five initial bytes you seem to have in `byte_array`.

Note that this is obviously a crude experiment in exploiting program vulnerabilities. As attractive as the notion may be, carrying off successful exploits requires considerably more knowledge than this question suggests, and it is not the best route to learning software engineering in general.